# How to return a JSON string into useable data?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am using a plug-in that groups my products and then uses JSON stringify to take the product IDs and return the following in a custom field: [{"id":"435"},{"id":"527"},{"id":"563"},{"id":"568"}].

I would like to use that, but cannot figure out how. I don't know Java at all. I am using Wordpress + WooCommerce. I would like to get these posts by their ID. In The Loop, I am calling the custom field by

```
<?php
    while (have_posts()) { the_post(); $count++;

        // post data from "Single_Menu" custom field
        echo do_shortcode(get_post_field("menu_listing", $post->ID ));

    } // End WHILE Loop
```

This is what returns on the web page

```
[{"id":"435"},{"id":"527"},{"id":"563"},{"id":"568"}]
```

which is what is in the backend meta box. What I want is to return the actual posts that correlate to those IDs. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in php function [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn that json string into either an array of arrays or an array of objects.

```
$json = '[{"id":"435"},{"id":"527"},{"id":"563"},{"id":"568"}]';
$array = json_decode($json);
```

You now have an array of objects that you can use.  Put those ids into another array to use as part of the arguments parameter for [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

```
$include = array();
foreach($array as $a) {
    $include[] = $a->ID;
}

$args = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'include' => $include);
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

`$posts` is now an array of post objects that you can use as you please.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but neither are working. I put your code in my loop and the string "[{"id":"435"},{"id":"527"},{"id":"563"},{"id":"568"}]" is all that returns. I thought it was a glitch (that my site wasn't updating), so I waited several hours and I also restarted my machine. I tried this too: `$json = do_shortcode(get_post_field("menu_listing", $post->ID ));

  $array = print_r(json_decode($json, true));

  $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'product',
   'meta_query' => $include,
   );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );`
 and that still is just returning the string.

Comment: My site might not be updating right now. I just tried removing all the code in my php file and the string is still appearing on the web page.

Comment: I have been playing around with this for several days now, and am not getting the results I want. The best I've been able to achieve is the page pulling in all the posts, not just the ones part of the $json string.

Comment: I reposted my problem, with the code in its entirety, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974878/processing-json-decode-to-use-in-get-posts